# random the link everytime the page is refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, random, logic

I'm trying to figure out how can I make one anchor tag that will everytime change when the page is refresh random from the list I have.

Say I have this list

```
<a href="http://testpage.com/">This is the first one</a>
<a href="http://testpage.com/">This is the second one</a>
<a href="http://testpage.com/">This is the third one</a>
```

This is the first one 
This is the second one 
This is the third one

it is like Link Unit ads that Adsense has but I just want it to do simple random not to do any kind of extra work like check if is relate the topic or not like adsense does.

Please advice me what can I do.

Thanks

Comment: Use Math.random() and assign each tag to a range. But this would be much easier using php.

Comment: Where is the anchors list coming from? A JS Array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="http://testpage.com/">
<script type="text/javascript">
    // This script will replace itself with a random one of these phrases
    var phrases = [
        'This is the first one',
        'This is the second one',
        'This is the third one'
    ];

    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var this_script = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
    this_script.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(phrases[Math.floor(Math.random()*phrases.length)]), this_script);
</script>
</a>​
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/vpAHz/)

---

**Breakdown**

Create an array literal containing three strings:

```
var phrases = [
    'This is the first one',
    'This is the second one',
    'This is the third one'
];
```

Get a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList) of all [script elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/script) on the page (as the page has loaded up to this point, so all scripts before and including this one):

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
```

Store the last script in that list (IE. this script element) in `this_script`:

```
var this_script = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
```

I'll break this next line up into smaller segments.
[Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) gives a [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) between `0` (inclusive) and `1` (exclusive). Multiplying it by 3 gives an even distribution between `0` (inclusive) and `3` (exclusive) and [Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) truncates it. This gives a random integer between `0` and `2` inclusive. If you add elements to the array it will update because it uses phrases.length in the calculation, instead of a literal 3:

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*phrases.length)
```

[document.createTextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3adocument.createTextNode) creates and returns a new Node implementing the Text interface, it's data is just the value that's passed in. In this case it's a random element from the phrases array:

```
document.createTextNode(phrases[Math.floor(Math.random()*phrases.length)])
```

[Node.parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.parentNode) is self explanatory, in this case the parent of the script element will be the [HTMLAnchorElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLAnchorElement) (that is represented by the `<a>` tag above the script in the tree). [Node.replaceChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.replaceChild) takes in two arguments, a `new_child` and an `old_child`.  We passed in our new Text Node for `new child`, and this script for `old_child`, which causes this script to be removed from the DOM and replaced with the Text Node:

```
this_script.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(phrases[Math.floor(Math.random()*phrases.length)]), this_script);
```

Comment: This is awesome! I'm going to get to understand it a bit so in the future I can use it sometime too myself!

Comment: @Ali Great! :) Let me know if you want me to break it down a bit and explain it.

Comment: Pretty interesting way how you take advantage of JS Arrays' 0-based nature by getting the `floor` of the `random(0-1)*array.length` to give an equal chance for each item. +1

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. I would love to! I'm actually studying Computer Programming in Seneca @ York and I really like to know more...

Answer (score 1):

You could use php like this:

```
<?php $linkName = mt_rand(1,3);
 if ($linkName == 1) echo '<a href="http://testpage.com/">This is the first one</a>';
 if ($linkName == 2) echo '<a href="http://testpage.com/">This is the second one</a>';
 if ($linkName == 3) echo '<a href="http://testpage.com/">This is the third one</a>';
?>
```

Comment: Note that the question is about JS.