# Link randomizer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Well I thought of this one and I have no ideas how it can be made... I thought to search up for help over here. I am just html/css newbie programmer and I dont know to make javascripts or scripts with jquery help ...

Anyway... This is my explanation.

Lets say I have an download button.

```
<a onclick="run"><div id="download-button"></div></a>
```

There will be rest in css for normal and active state... Lets skip it here.

Now what I need is javascript I guess?

I want that onclick "run" to trigger that script where I can copy/paste a couple of links for download...

Lets say I have 5 links that redirects to eg.(rapidshare)...

I wanna paste this five links in that javascript, so download button randomly pick one link. Example... Downloading link no 4.

So if I keep clicking on it it will randomly redirect to one link... 1,2,3,4,5 doesnt matter :) (if possible, it wont repeat same link again). If not possible, repeating same link is fine.

Is this even possible? I guess some math count things in javascript or something :D I dont know how javascript works so I cannot make, really.

I also know that this site is not "Come, ask question and get everything done"... But please, if you just can help me with this javascript trouble? I dont even know to write anything except `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where's the list of items to be randomized? Inside a JS array?

Comment: I guess? Well wherever is possible...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/10843431/1331430

Comment: At the moment, it looks like the OP has it in a text document, and would like to be able to paste it in.

Comment: This is really nice
<?php $linkName = mt_rand(1,3);
 if ($linkName == 1) echo '<a href="http://testpage.com/">This is the first one</a>';
 if ($linkName == 2) echo '<a href="http://testpage.com/">This is the second one</a>';
 if ($linkName == 3) echo '<a href="http://testpage.com/">This is the third one</a>';
?>

but php... possible with javascript ? I saw the checked as correct answer @fabio, but I also see only one same link for all three randomize parts...

Comment: Whether or not it's a duplicate, if you can manage to figure out enough of the link @FabrícioMatté posted to make use of it, that should handle your issue nicely (and has a lot of useful explanation for you, if you want to learn more about javascript)

Comment: Nenad, Yes, use the answer above that one. :) it even has a fiddle which you can refresh/run multiple times, it'll pick a random link from that array every time you execute it. The answerer even gave a deep detail explanation of every line. =]

Comment: Okay great... An answer would be nice, to check it as correct? Thanks ;) fabricio

Comment: Point is, the contents inside the script tag on htat link will replace themselves with one of the strings (chosen at random) from inside var phrases.  You can put whatever you want in there - straight text or full-fledged tags.  Mind you, you will have to do some quote wrangling, but it should handle your problem.  For the quote wrangling, if you're using `"` on the outside, use `'` on the inside, or vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put all your links inside an Array (assume `myArray`), then you can call:

```
var randomItem = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
```

To select a random item from that array.

**[Reference + details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843395/random-the-link-everytime-the-page-is-refresh/10843431#10843431)**

Answer (score 3):

Here you have a jquery solution:

HTML:

```
<div id="button">
  link
  <a class="button-link" href="http://www.google.com">a</a>
  <a class="button-link" href="http://www.yahoo.com">b</a>
  <a class="button-link" href="http://www.bing.com">c</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#button {
  background: red;
}
#button a.button-link {
  display: none;
}​
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $("#button").click(function () {
    var $anchors = $(this).find("a.button-link");
    var $anchor = $($anchors[Math.floor(Math.random()*$anchors.length)]);
    window.open($anchor.attr("href"),'_blank');
  });​
});
```

And last, but not least, [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CUzxd/2/).

Comment: `.length` is preferred over `.size()` as it doesn't have a function call overhead as per [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/size/). The detail is nice nonetheless, even though your demo has some flaws.

Comment: both answers are cool... ill play with both ;) 

thanks chango and fabricio!

Comment: You have a typo in `lenght` which should be `length`, otherwise +1. Obviously in your example, the function can be fired multiple times, but I assumed OP will use in a different way. :)